# Equivalence between derived categories preserve distinguished triangles

Tags: homological-algebra, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory, group-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

I have a problem: Is it true that every equivalence between derived categories preserve their distinguished triangles? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

Not necessarily.  For instance, the shift functor is an automorphism of any triangulated category, but it usually does not preserve distinguished triangles (because the shift of a distinguished triangle need not be distinguished, only the shift *with the signs of all the maps reversed* is distinguished).  For a general discussion of equivalences of triangulated categories as categories equipped with a shift functor that do not preserve the triangulation, see the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4653/classifying-triangulated-structures-on-a-graded-category) on MO.  In particular, the accepted answer there details how the shift fails to preserve distinguished triangles in the derived category of $\mathbb{Z}$.

If you don't care whether your equivalence preserves the shift functor, there are even easier examples.  For instance, the derived category of a semisimple ring $A$ is equivalent to the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded $A$-modules, and any bijection $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ induces an automorphism of the latter category via the grading.  Almost all of these fail to commute with the shift, so they trivially cannot preserve distinguished triangles.